# Last insert id in diffrent table mySql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, insert, sql-insert

I have 2 table like this below:

```
create TABLE person(
id INTEGER not NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
name VARCHAR(255), 
surrname VARCHAR(255)
); 


create TABLE users(
id INTEGER not NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
login VARCHAR(50), 
password VARCHAR(50),
person_id int references person(id)
);
```

I add insert to table 'person':

```
Insert into person(name,surrname) values ('mark','second');
```

And now my problem begins because when i try add insert to table 'users',
I have to put the last added id in the table 'person'.

```
Insert into users
        (login,password,person_id) 
values ('login123','pass123',>here must be last added id from person table<);`
```

In the oracle database I would use a sequence but not possible here. Can someone know what value should be there?

Comment: After the first insert, use the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` with the next insert.

Comment: the next insert should look like this?

Insert into users
        (login,password,person_id) 
values ('login123','pass123',LAST_INSERT_ID());`

Comment: Assuming the queries are using the same connection, one after the other, and no error with the first insert, yes. The values part of the second query could be: `...values ('login123','pass123', LAST_INSERT_ID());`

Comment: Yes its working but I would like to do this differently. I I would like to add first insert and in the next connection, next insert? It is possible?

Comment: Can someone help me? Becouse i finally need to this on java and in JDBC i cant do two insert in one statment so this is big problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes its working but I would like to do this differently. I I would like to add first insert and in the next connection, next insert? It is possible?

You do need to get the last insert id in the same connection as the first insert. If you do it immediately after the insert you can return it as a result set, and save it in a variable in your application:

```
INSERT INTO person(name,surrname) VALUES ('mark','second');

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Handle the latter statement like you would any other SELECT statement that returns a value. Save it in a variable in your Java program.

Then use that Java variable in a subsequent INSERT, binding it as a value for a parameterized statement:

```
Insert into users
        (login,password,person_id) 
values ('login123','pass123',?);`
```

There are plenty of guides for passing a Java variable to a parameterized SQL statement. For example: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Answer (score -1):

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/insertreturning/

This will let you return the id

```
Insert into person(name,surrname) values ('mark','second') returning id;
```

Comment: Note that syntax requires at least v10.5.

Comment: Oh yeah....the title specifically says MySQL too, so this probably isn't acceptable.  I can't find reference to MySQL implementing that.

Comment: I confirm that no version of MySQL through at least 8.0 implements the RETURNING clause. By now, we really need to think of MariaDB as a distinct product, since it has been adding its own features since it forked in 2010.